# User Data in launch configuration of amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was trying to create an EBS volume by writing a shell script in the user data of my launch configuration. I don't think there is anything wrong with my bash script. I kept looking up creating launch configuration and writing user data in AWS websites, but could not find anything more than what I did below. For my launch configuration, I used Amazon Linux 2 AMI which has pre-built AWS CLI. So I just wrote the following code in my user data:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    aws ec2 create-volume \
        --volume-type gp2 \
        --size 100 \
        --encrypted \
        --availability-zone us-east-1c
    
    aws ec2 create-volume \
        --volume-type gp2 \
        --size 100 \
        --encrypted \
        --availability-zone us-east-1d
```

As you can see I am trying to create EBS volumes in two availability zones, but I just could not find out why it does not create any volume for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the EC2 instance has permissions to create the volumes. See https://aws.nz/best-practice/ec2-instance-roles/
2. Check for the errors in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` and (much more verbose) `/var/log/cloud-init.log`
3. Be aware that you can't attach volumes from other AZs to your EC2, so not quite sure why you would want to create them from the launch script.
4. *(added based on comments)* Specify region: `aws --region us-east-1 ec2 create-volume ...`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: We can attach volumes from launch script but creating volumes I am not so sure. I am not sure why it's not being created at all, the volume with the region and availability zones that I have mentioned. My mentor has let me know that this kind of problem falls under the infrastructure management.

Comment: About the permission, I have given the administrator access to the IAM role that I have created for the user.

Comment: About the second point, where can I find the var/log/cloud-init-output.log. Also what do you mean by we cannot attach volumes from other availability zones. The ec2 instance that I have created and the availability zones that I have set for the volume are same. Right now I just want to create two volumes based on availability zones.

Comment: @Ufomammut are there any issues reported in `cloud-init-output.log`? Are the commands actually run? Do you see the calls in CloudTrail?

Comment: Hey I am new to aws and I don't know where to look for tthis cloud-init-output.log?

Comment: It’s in my answer - `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Comment: You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".

Comment: Jan 09 23:45:05 cloud-init[3388]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [255]
Jan 09 23:45:05 cloud-init[3388]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Jan 09 23:45:05 cloud-init[3388]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 18.5-2.amzn2 finished at Thu, 09 Jan 2020 23:45:05 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 17.85 seconds

Comment: Hey this is what I found in my cloud-init-output.log

Comment: @Ufomammut See, pretty self-explanatory. Simply use `aws --region us-east-1 ec2 create-volume ...`

Comment: Updated the answer. If it works please upvote and accept it.

Comment: Let me see but I think I tried putting only us-east-1. Let me try it again.

Comment: Finally it works

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103174/discussion-between-ufomammut-and-mlu).